# How to read values from a text file and saving as the custom property[SOAP UI]

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have two values in the text file as follows:

```
12345
67895
```

I want to save these two values as two custom properties so I can use it in my soap request.

This is what I have so far but no luck:

```
def myTestCase = context.testCase

// configure the path to your textfile here
File tempFile = new File("C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject\testdata.txt")
List lines = tempFile.readLines()
```

I am getting this error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script22.groovy: 4: unexpected char: '\' @ line 4, column 29. File tempFile = new File("C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject\testdata.txt") ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected char: '\' @ line 4, column 29. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:135) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:138) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: Script22.groovy:4:29: unexpected char: '\' at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer.mESC(GroovyLexer.java:2180) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer.mSTRING_CTOR_END(GroovyLexer.java:2226) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer.mSTRING_LITERAL(GroovyLexer.java:1985) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer.nextToken(GroovyLexer.java:468) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer$1.nextToken(GroovyLexer.java:258) at groovyjarjarantlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69) at groovyjarjarantlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80) at groovyjarjarantlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.nls(GroovyRecognizer.java:796) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.newExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:13525) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.primaryExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:10993) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.pathExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:11595) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.postfixExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:13332) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.unaryExpressionNotPlusMinus(GroovyRecognizer.java:13301) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.powerExpressionNotPlusMinus(GroovyRecognizer.java:13005) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.multiplicativeExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12937) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.additiveExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12607) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.shiftExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:9824) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.relationalExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12512) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.equalityExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12436) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.regexExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12384) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.andExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12352) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.exclusiveOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12320) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.inclusiveOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12288) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.logicalAndExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12256) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.logicalOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12224) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.conditionalExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:4850) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.assignmentExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:8027) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expression(GroovyRecognizer.java:10001) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expressionStatementNoCheck(GroovyRecognizer.java:8353) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.varInitializer(GroovyRecognizer.java:2682) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDeclarator(GroovyRecognizer.java:7928) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.listOfVariables(GroovyRecognizer.java:7882) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDefinitions(GroovyRecognizer.java:2278) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.declaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:2165) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1208) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:757) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:131) ... 20 more 1 error

Comment: Are they separated by just space or on separate lines? Is this similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402086/groovy-script-automatic-request-and-saving-response-from-soap-ui/40409510#40409510

Comment: It is just on separate lines

Comment: Then solution provided in the other question should be applicable to you, please give a try. Have you looked at the given link?

Comment: is it possible for me to use this intead? def file = new File('C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject\testdata.txt')
lastline = file.readLines()
log.info lastline

Comment: Did not get you. May be you want explain the use case in detailed manner? Did not under stand the actual issue.

Comment: Please see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have trivial error.

Please use forward slash `/` instead of `\` for the file path.

```
def tempFile = new File("C:/Users/cverma/Desktop/SOAPProject/testdata.txt")
tempFile.eachLine {
   log.info "Current data : ${it}"
}
```

Comment: @user5653362, glad to know that the answer is helpful.

Comment: Old, but others may come across this. Even better, make this platform independent and so that you don't have to remember the platforms file conventions, for the file separator don't hard code, but use:
+ File.separator +

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to write this in a platform independent way, with the additional advantage that you don't have to remember the platforms file conventions, if you are going to use the project directory in the path you can use this:

```
def testdata = context.expand('${projectDir}') + File.separator + "testdata.txt"
def tempFile = new File(testdata)
...
```