# How to pass a request param dynamically in Testcase in SOAP UI Testing Tool

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui, spock

I am using SOAP UI for API test . Recently I created a testcase using REST REQUEST, send request params using groovy script like below images.

[image]

[image]

But how to pass Request params (version and authProvider ) dynamically in one testcase . Is it Possible in SOAP UI ?

Same scenerio i did in Spock test by WHERE block.

[image]

FirstTime version - "v1" and authProvider - "Salesforce" 
 SecondTime version - "v2" and authProvider - "Bullhorn"

Is it possible in SOAPI UI? or need to  write another testcase for different request?

Comment: You may need to use data driven approach in order to achieve the same. It appears that this post is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402086/groovy-script-automatic-request-and-saving-response-from-soap-ui. so please check if that is useful.

Comment: Thanks Rao for your quick response. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402086/groovy-script-automatic-request-and-saving-response-from-soap-ui) in this post, using file content as request . for example , order.txt - first time ,orderId as 34 again i will check different orderId means (56,54..) ,need to change the file content of order.txt right?

Comment: You need to have all the data that you would like to iterate with in the data source file.

Comment: I am using SOAP UI (Open Source ) not a PRO edition. Data source option is only available in PRO edition .

Comment: That is right, the link provided in the first comments handle the data source using groovy script.

Comment: Any option to send request dynamic without data source  in SOAP UI (Open source ) ?

Comment: That was contradictory.