# Automatic Data Driven tests in SoapUI via Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

as discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402086/groovy-script-automatic-request-and-saving-response-from-soap-ui) in soapUI free version i'm trying to call this WS:

```
    <soap:Body>
<RequestParameters>
    <Parameter name="key" value="SomeorderId"/>
</RequestParameters>
    </soap:Body>
```

and i want to take the values of "key" from a local data.txt file on my desktop. the content of this file:

```
9999999991
9999999992
9999999993
```

to do so, i've created a test suite with below three test steps:

1.first step: a groovy script:

```
def data = new File('C:/Users/Polarick/Desktop/data.txt') 
data.eachLine { orderId ->
   context.orderId = orderId
   //Get the step2, index of the step is 1
   def step = context.testCase.getTestStepAt(1)
   //Run the step2
   step.run(testRunner, context)
}
//all the orders got executed,jump to step2, index is 2
testRunner.gotoStep(2)
```

2.second step: modifying request:

```
<Parameter name="MSISDN" value="${orderId}"/>
```

and asserting this script to it:

```
//Check if there is response
assert context.request, "Request is empty or null"

//Save the contents to a file
def saveToFile(file, content) {
    if (!file.parentFile.exists()) {
         file.parentFile.mkdirs()
         log.info "Directory did not exist, created"
    }
    file.write(content) 
    assert file.exists(), "${file.name} not created"
}

def response = context.expand( '${Step2#Response}' )
def f = new File("C:/Users/Polarick/Desktop/${context.orderId}_Response.xml")
f.write(response, "UTF-8")
saveToFile(f, context.response)
```

3.Third step: a groovy script:

```
log.info "Test completed."
```

It all works fine and calls the WS for all lines existing in data.txt file sequentially, but i'm expecting to find a response .xml file per execution, for example:

```
C:/Users/Polarick/Desktop/9999999991_Response.xml
C:/Users/Polarick/Desktop/9999999992_Response.xml
C:/Users/Polarick/Desktop/9999999993_Response.xml
```

but there is no response file generated,
can you help?

Comment: Do the soapUI script or error logs show any errors or exceptions?

Comment: i'm getting this error on soap step(2nd step): Request is empty or null. Expression: context.request

Comment: Store the values as properties, and parameterise it in the request XML like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525954/how-can-i-make-requests-in-a-loop-in-soapui-with-different-content/58535311#58535311